# flutter automatic testing : Tap on a button don't work in drawer

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to do some TDD with flutter and when the test is running,  tapping on a button doesn't work if it's in a drawer. The button works perfectly fine with a normal user.

In the following example we press on two buttons which print a message in the console. Here's the actions :
locate and tap on a button in the scaffold: OK
open the drawer: OK
Locate button in drawer: OK
Tap on the drawer button: **nothing happen**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Test that drawer is apparing and we can click on button',
  (WidgetTester tester) async {
final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

await tester.pumpWidget(new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Where Assistant',
  home: Scaffold(
    key: scaffoldKey,
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('test text'),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print('OK on main screen');
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    drawer: Drawer(
      // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
      // through the options in the Drawer if there isn't enough vertical
      // space to fit everything.
      child: ListView(
        // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Item 2'),
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app
              // ...
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('OK drawer');
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
));

await tester.pump();

expect(find.text('test text'), findsOneWidget);
expect(find.byIcon(Icons.access_alarm), findsOneWidget);
await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.access_alarm));
expect(find.byIcon(Icons.add), findsNothing);

scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
await tester.pump(); // drawer should appear

expect(find.text('Item 2'), findsOneWidget);
expect(find.byIcon(Icons.add), findsOneWidget);
await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
print('end of test');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

finally found a workaround : just need to add some delay before tapping in the drawer.

So I added

```
await tester.pump(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
```

before tapping on buttons

Comment: Probably `await tester.pumpAndSettle();` is better solution. It just waits until animation is over.
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/widget/tap-drag#4-ensure-swipe-to-dismiss-removes-the-todo

Answer (score 9):

I also ran into a similar issue.

The tester was able to find the FlatButton in the drawer:

```
expect(find.byType(FlatButton), findsOneWidget);
```

tester.tap did not appear to be working:

```
await tester.tap(find.byType(FlatButton));
```

But the solution mentioned in this [Flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31066) did work:

```
FlatButton button = find.widgetWithText(FlatButton, 'TextExample').evaluate().first.widget;
button.onPressed();
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't played with `WidgetTest` yet, but I was able to achieve tapping on a button inside drawer, with flutter driver.

```
  test('test button tap in drawer', () async {

    final SerializableFinder drawerOpenButton = find.byTooltip('Open navigation menu');
    final SerializableFinder btn = find.byValueKey('firstButton');

    await driver.waitFor(drawerOpenButton);
    await driver.tap(drawerOpenButton);
    await driver.waitFor(btn);
    await driver.tap(btn);
    print('tapped');
    });
```

In `main.dart`, I used `key` property for the `RaisedButton` I want to tap on.

Answer (score 1):

### Wait for Drawer to Open *Fully*

Drawer opening is an animation, sliding out over time.

Until the Drawer is fully extended we shouldn't try testing taps for widgets inside it.

`pumpAndSettle()` or "double pump" after initiating `.openDrawer()` are two solutions.

---

`pumpAndSettle()`

```
final ScaffoldState scafState = tester.firstState(find.byType(Scaffold));
scafState.openDrawer();
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
// do taps below here
```

- if you have other animations running during test, this won't "settle" / return until *all* animations are complete or 10 minutes has passed (default timeout).

### ...or

Double `pump()`

```
final ScaffoldState scafState = tester.firstState(find.byType(Scaffold));
scafState.openDrawer();
await tester.pump(); // 99% of Drawer still offstage
await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 1)); // ←- This is important
// do taps below here
```

---

`scaffoldState.openDrawer();`

- Drawer opening has been "requested"
- but nothing has changed onstage yet (nothing built/laid out/painted), Drawer is 100% offstage
- Drawer widgets are offstage / cannot be tapped

#### pumpAndSettle()

`await tester.pumpAndSettle();`

- pumps a single frame every 100ms while (any) animations are ongoing
- in between 100ms waits, this does nothing
- returns when `binder.hasScheduledFrame` is false (no more animation frames, from Drawer opening ***or other animations***)

#### Double pump()

`await tester.pump();`

- triggers a build/layout/paint, **starting the animation**
- only the ***first*** frame of the Drawer opening animation here
- 99% of Drawer contents are still offstage & untappable
- hit targets are offstage / cannot be tapped

`await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 1);`

- this waits a full second *before* calling `pump()` (again) to "render" a frame of current situation.  (This cannot be used alone to start & wait for animation to complete as this waits 1 second to pass ***then*** calls `pump()` once. That would only *start* the animation.)
- animation started by previous `pump()` has had 1000ms (of mostly skipped frames) to complete
- Drawer should be fully open and entirety of Drawer contents should be onstage
- should be OK to do find/tap of Drawer button widgets now
- a [Scaffold tests](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/material/scaffold_test.dart#L410) and [Drawer tests](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/material/drawer_test.dart) on the Flutter framework itself use this technique

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the `onTap` callback for the `GestureDetector` was too deep in the Widget Tree,

I ended up creating a new `stateless Widget` type which directly wraps up the `GestureListener` and passes the necessary data there.

So the `find.byWidgetPredicate((widget) => widget is ActionClickableButton).first` worked.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code.. this is work on drawer click..

```
class DrawerItem {
 String title;
 IconData icon;

 DrawerItem(this.title, this.icon);
}


 class MyHomeScreenStateFull extends StatefulWidget {
 // here define drawer item
 final drawerItems = [
 new DrawerItem("Home", Icons.save),
 new DrawerItem("Event", Icons.local_pizza)

];

@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
// TODO: implement createState
return MyHomeScreenState();
}
}

class MyHomeScreenState extends State<MyHomeScreenStateFull> {
int selectedDrawerIndex = 0;
// here define other screen.
 getDrawerItemWidget(int pos) {
 switch (pos) {
  case 0:
    return new FirstFragmentStateFull();
  case 1:
    return new SecondFragmentStateFull();

  default:
    return new Text("Error");
 }
 }

 onSelectItem(int index) {
setState(() => selectedDrawerIndex = index);
Navigator.of(context).pop(); // close the drawer
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var drawerOptions = <Widget>[];
for (var i = 0; i < widget.drawerItems.length; i++) {
  var d = widget.drawerItems[i];
  drawerOptions.add(new ListTile(
    leading: new Icon(d.icon),
    title: new Text(
      d.title,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
    ),
    selected: i == selectedDrawerIndex,
    onTap: () => onSelectItem(i),
  ));
  }

  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: new Text(widget.drawerItems[selectedDrawerIndex].title),
  ),
  /*body: Center(
    child: Text("Welcome To Home"),
  ),*/
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
          accountName: Text("Vikas Pandey "),
          accountEmail: null,
          currentAccountPicture: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: NetworkImage(
                        "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952"))),
          ),
        ),
        new Column(
          children: drawerOptions,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
  body: getDrawerItemWidget(selectedDrawerIndex),
);
}
}
```

Comment: Drawer and buttons work perfectly with a normal user. That's when I use the flutter testing framework that I can't achieve to tap on a button in a drawer. I edit my post to make it clear.